# Styles based on number of children

Tags: css, sass

I have a container (`.homepage-section`) and inside this there could be up to three `.widget`'s. Depending on how many `.widget`'s there inside of `.homepage-section`, I'd like the widths to change.

I've followed the approach outlined by Lea Verou ([link](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/)) but with no success.

Here's the SASS function I've written (so far):

```
.widget {
     @for $i from 1 through 3 {
       &:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(#{$i}),
       &:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(#{$i}) ~ .widget {
         width: (1000px / #{$i});
       }
     }
  }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKwte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
.widget {
  @for $j from 2 through 5 {
    @for $i from 1 through $j {
      &:nth-of-type(#{$j + 1 - $i}):nth-last-of-type(#{$i}),
      &:nth-of-type(#{$j + 1 - $i}):nth-last-of-type(#{$i}) ~ .widget {
        width: (1000px / $j);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(see the [edited pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qcLvs)).

The general rule — for each count of widgets, the sum of numbers in `nth-*` and `nth-last-*` must be the number of widgets plus 1, and the overall width must be divided by the number of widgets.